# Boolean not working for 2 objects, not sure why. Tried many things as suggested on tutorial sites

Tags: modifiers

I hope to get some help here.
I am having some fun designing a House, but for some reason I cannot get two boolean objects to cut properly.
I hope to get some help to figure out why the Windows and Pantry Door work, but the Bed4 and Side Window wont cut the hole.

I have tried the normals settings and nothing seems to work.
the only way I have got a result is to actually apply a boolean then edit the mesh that object was around to create the opening. but it's not a great way as I would like to keep it UN-Applied to move objects around to get a better feel for the placements etc.

none the less I have tried for hours and I am over it! heeheehee
I hope with some input from others I may understand what i've done wrong.

I really want to figure it out more then anything haha

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12nheFu0Or7YljisuJXRR3k69tRx_r4AD/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: your link asks for authorization  ;)   are you sure that some edges, faces or vertices are not overlapping?

Comment: Try it now buddy

Comment: it works, except your objects are just not full objects, so it justs create edges, not holes

Comment: Sorry man. Can you explain what changes I need to make to the objects? I want the walls to have holes just like the big doors at the rear

Comment: for the moment your boolean object is this: https://zupimages.net/up/20/43/2zww.jpg ... you need to fill the faces if you want them to cut a hole in your main object: https://zupimages.net/up/20/43/ngbs.jpg

Comment: well it still bugs

Comment: I must admit. I have had faces around it. The rear windows have two opposite sides without faces

Comment: So it is bugs in blender? I hope so it was driving me absolutely bonkers

Comment: so yes, Booleans bug most of the time because of overlapping vertices/edges/faces, these bugs will end with next Blender version, but there are 2 things here: you need to have a filled boolean object and your wall needs thickness

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.91 and 2.92alpha
Problem is solved as it uses a more accurate boolean